# Why does kernel 4.4.0-135 need an explicit upgrade instead of the usual apt upgrade?

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, kernel

On several Ubuntu (16.04 LTS, Xenial) systems `apt list --upgradable` tells me that kernel upgrades are available:

```
$ apt list --upgradable
initramfs-tools/xenial-updates,xenial-updates 0.122ubuntu8.12 all [upgradable from: 0.122ubuntu8.11]
initramfs-tools-bin/xenial-updates 0.122ubuntu8.12 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.122ubuntu8.11]
initramfs-tools-core/xenial-updates,xenial-updates 0.122ubuntu8.12 all [upgradable from: 0.122ubuntu8.11]
linux-generic/xenial-updates 4.4.0.135.141 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.4.0.134.140]
linux-headers-generic/xenial-updates 4.4.0.135.141 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.4.0.134.140]
linux-image-generic/xenial-updates 4.4.0.135.141 amd64 [upgradable from: 4.4.0.134.140]
```

However, a `apt upgrade` does **not** upgrade the kernel. Instead, an explicit `apt upgrade linux-generic` (or one of the other packages) is necessary and would install the `4.4.0-135` packages:

```
$ apt-get upgrade linux-generic --dry-run
  .. snip ..
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-135 linux-headers-4.4.0-135-generic linux-image-4.4.0-135-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-135-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin initramfs-tools-core linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
6 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

That's unusual. **Why does `linux-generic` suddenly need a `-version` package?** The `-130`, `-133` and `134` versions didn't need an explicit upgrade or a `dist-upgrade`, and where installed either with `apt upgrade` or `unattended-upgrade`. Is there something special about `4.4.0-135`?

<sup>(Note: I know how to upgrade the kernel, I'd like to know *why* `4.4.0-135` doesn't follow the usual `apt upgrade` policy)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu, we don't upgrade a Kernel. Actually we install the newer version and keep an old version just in case of any failure in booting system with new kernel and remove the others.

As you know installing new packages while upgrading the system take palace using `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

The `linux-generic` package is a dummy package. Dummy packages points you to the real package:

```
apt show linux-generic
```

> It will always depend on the latest complete generic Linux kernel
>    and headers.

So instead of checking for new version and install it manually, having `linux-generic` will take care of this job for us.

At the end when you are using `apt upgrade` it will install new packages while `apt-get` neeeds `dist-upgrade` to install new packages.

Comment: My point is: a `dist-upgrade` wasn't necessary for `4.4.0-131`, `4.4.0-132`, `4.4.0-133` and others. Why is it necessary for `4.4.0-135`? *That's* the essence of my question, which your answer unfortunately misses.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't use `apt upgrade`?

Comment: `apt-get upgrade` is different from `apt upgrade` ...

Answer (score 1):

**`apt` != `apt-get`**

The traditional `apt-get` has the following upgrade-related commands:

- `apt-get upgrade` will upgrade packages to newer versions *without* installing new or removing  other packages.
- `apt-get dist-upgrade` will upgrade packages as well, but is also able to handle upgrades with changing dependencies by installing new or removing old packages if necessary.

The newer interface `apt` interprets different options:

- `apt upgrade` of course upgrades packages again, but it also can install new packages to fulfill changing dependencies, unlike `apt-get upgrade`. It does never remove packages though.
- `apt full-upgrade` is equivalent to `apt-get dist-upgrade` in that it can both install and remove packages if this is required by changed dependencies of the newer package version.

Kernel upgrades work by upgrading the meta-package (e.g. `linux-image-generic`) to a newer version, which then has a changed dependency on the latest `linux-image-X.Y.Z-AAA-generic` package. That means, `apt-get upgrade` can never upgrade kernels, but `apt-get dist-upgrade`, `apt full-upgrade` or even `apt upgrade` can.